# pandas df select columns based on cell values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and would like to drop all columns where the first row is not `True`. How can I do this?
So for example if I have this df I would like to get the column `y` back. I don't want to enter any column names though.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[False, True, False, True], 'y':[True, False, True, True], 'z':[False, False,False,False]})
```

Comment: `df.loc[:, df.iloc[0] == True]`?

Comment: @It_is_Chris. Shortcut: `df.loc[:, df.iloc[0]]` :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a loop (preferably a list comprehension) to do it inplace.
So, you will not need to assign the generated dataframe to a new variable.
Please, look at the example below.

Given that you have the following pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [True, False, True],
                   "b": [False, False, True],
                   "c": [True, True, True]})
```

You the loop below removes the column b.

```
[df.drop([col], axis=1, inplace=True) 
for col in df.columns 
if df[col].loc[0] == False]
```

Usually, we use "is" to check bool conditions.
However, the benefit of the double equal sign here is that works properly with both, bool and numpy.bool.